# Opencv and python - Shading area between two lines

Tags: python, opencv

I've got some working code, but performance is awful and it can be done better, so lets see how it can be optimized.

I have an image with two semi-vertical lines drawn and would like to shade the area between those two lines.  My current code iterates pixel by pixel, which is painfully slow in python.

```
#Get starting images
shade_image = np.zeros_like(image)
line_image = plot_lines(shade_image, left_line, right_line)
#Choose color
shade_color = [0, 255, 0]
#Iterate through and fill blank image
left_switch = False
right_switch = False
for i in range(0, image.shape[0]):
    left_switch = False
    right_switch = False
    for j in range(0, image.shape[1]):
        if left_switch & right_switch: shade_image[i][j] = shade_color
        #Find left edge of left line
        if (not left_switch) & (not right_switch) & np.any(line_image[i][j] != 0):
            left_switch = True
        #Find right edge of left line
        elif left_switch & (not right_switch) & np.all(line_image[i][j] == 0):
            right_switch = True
        #Find left edge of left line
        elif left_switch & right_switch & np.any(line_image[i][j] != 0):
            break
        #In case of a single line, no shading
        elif left_switch & right_switch & (j == (image.shape[1] - 1)):
             shade_image[i].fill(0)
#Shade lane area
output_image = cv2.addWeighted(image, 1.0, shade_image, 1.0, gamma=0.0)
```

Not pretty.  I'm thinking somehow this can be done by using all the nonzeros in the line_image and creating a mask, but I don't know how to fill between the left and right points.  I tried using fillPolygon but I don't really know how to convert all the nonzero's into vertices.

If it helps, the shading can also incorporate the lines, this isn't exact.

---

@Alxeander - Very helpful!  I'm almost there, except now there is the issue of filling outside of a convex line due to the bounding box, like so:[image]

Alternatively, I ditched the cv2.convexHull and used the concatenated points directly as vertices of a polygon and got this result:[image]

Which follows the curvature, convex or concave, however because of the order of the points it flips when it goes left to right.  I've tried using np.flips(points2, 0) but no change.  I'll play with it some more, almost there.

---

Made a mistake with the np.flip(points2, 0), that worked!:[image]

Thanks for the help!

Comment: How are your lines defined? Do you have endpoints of the line at the image boundaries, do you have an equation, do you have angle and distance from the origin? Etc. You can definitely get this done with `fillPoly` or other methods which don't loop through each point like that, but it depends on how your lines are defined. It looks like you might be able to use the `line_image` to find the line endpoints on the first and last row by looking for the line color, and use that as your endpoints for `fillPoly`, but if the lines are defined before then you probably don't need the lines first at all.

Comment: Lines do not extend to top and bottom.  The lines are actually defined by a polynomial and I use plot_lines() to draw them with matplotlib.pyplot then convert them go a np.array (BGR)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since your lines are defined by a polynomial, that means you can easily get the point set from them. You have your domain values `x` and your polynomial values `y`. If you put these into a point array

```
points = np.array([[[x1, y1]], ..., [[xn, yn]]])
```

then you can pass these points into the OpenCV function [`cv2.fillPoly()`](http://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/modules/imgproc/doc/drawing_functions.html#fillpoly) or `cv2.drawContours()` to fill in the region.

Note that polynomials can easily define lines way outside your image bounds. In order to plot a contour or polygon you should use closed shapes, and it will be easier to cut those excess points out of your domain.

Here's a full example defining a region based on two polynomials and filling the region:

```
import numpy as np 
import cv2

img = cv2.imread('img1.png')
h, w = img.shape[:2]

x = np.arange(w)
polynomial1 = lambda x: x**2/800
polynomial2 = lambda x: x+200
y1 = polynomial1(x)
y2 = polynomial2(x)

points1 = np.array([[[xi, yi]] for xi, yi in zip(x, y1) if (0<=xi<w and 0<=yi<h)]).astype(np.int32)
points2 = np.array([[[xi, yi]] for xi, yi in zip(x, y2) if (0<=xi<w and 0<=yi<h)]).astype(np.int32)
points2 = np.flipud(points2)
points = np.concatenate((points1, points2))

polynomialgon = img.copy()
cv2.fillPoly(polynomialgon, [points], color=[255,255,255])
cv2.imshow('Polygon defined by two polynomials', polynomialgon)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Resulting in:

[image: Filled polygon defined by two polynomials]

Note that the `flipud` is to keep the points going in a clockwise fashion from the endpoints of the lines; otherwise where `polynomial1` ends, the line then goes up to where `polynomial2` begins, so we're backtracking and crossing over the region. It doesn't matter what the line does so long as the endpoints of the line are tracked clockwise or anti-clockwise.

Answer (score 0):

Alexander steered me in the right direction, I just had to tweak it for handling convex lines:

```
import numpy as np 
import cv2

img = cv2.imread('img1.png')
h, w = img.shape[:2]

x = np.arange(w)
polynomial1 = lambda x: x**2/800
polynomial2 = lambda x: x+200
y1 = polynomial1(x)
y2 = polynomial2(x)

points1 = np.array([[[xi, yi]] for xi, yi in zip(x, y1) if (0<=xi<w and 0<=yi<h)]).astype(np.int32)
points2 = np.array([[[xi, yi]] for xi, yi in zip(x, y2) if (0<=xi<w and 0<=yi<h)]).astype(np.int32)
points = np.concatenate(points1, np.flip(points2, 0))

polynomialgon = img.copy()
cv2.fillPoly(polynomialgon, [points], color=[255,255,255])
cv2.imshow('Polygon defined by two polynomials', polynomialgon)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```